# how to efficiently store pandas series in Postgresql?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, postgresql

I am trying to store a Pandas series column with around 3000 rows in a new table in Postgresql.This column is part of an excel file holding the time series data followed by a number of different sensors. My excel file looks like this :

```
dateTime sensor1 sensor2 ...sensor-n
2021-06-12 00:00:01 0.0,,,,
2021-06-13 00:00:03 0.0,1.0,,,
2021-06-14 00:00:05 0.0,,,,
...
```

If I store the name of the sensor and the pandas series for each sensor this will give me redundancy. Do you have any idea how can I store a pandas series efficiently for different sensors in Postgresql? Please help, I am new at Postgresql. Thank you.

Comment: I would create three tables, a `dim.calendar` table a `dim.sensor` table and a `fact.readings` you can then insert the data based on keys which will reduce redundancy in your database. That said you're question is quite vague, what have you done so far?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Until now I have built a table holding in one column the sensor name and on the another column the time series data. This is giving me the repetition of the name of the sensor many time and also redundancy. I am not please with my table.Can you please tell me a little bit more about how can these two table dim.calendar and dim.sensor have a relation? Thank you

Comment: `dim.sensor` will hold all the information of your sensors and a numeric `primary_key` for each sensor for example `sensor 1` = `1` .. `sensor n` = `n`. `dim.calendar` is not essential but allows you to use `datekeys` for joins which is faster and really aids business reporting. when inserting into your table you could first get these keys from the relevant tables before inserting into your readings table. so you would have `20210101, 1, reading` you'd have to `unpivot` or `melt` your dataframe first.

Comment: By "efficiently" here, it sounds to me like you're asking about how to _normalize_ the database schema. Is that correct?

Comment: @JeremyCaney yes